# show an image partially without canvas without frame or without plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this `img`, and a box `div` around it.

**http://jsfiddle.net/6d4yC/7/**

1) I want when the image is in its big size, only the part of image (250x150), without creating a white overlay over it. I put a #box1 div around the image and it can't limit the image that is shown.

2) When mouse leaves the picture, I want to break the animation even, and simply animate the image back to its big size.

How can I achieve these? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Add a `overflow: hidden` to your div.
2. Add a stop() to stop the current animation

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6d4yC/9/

Comment: BTW: add `position: relative; top: -10px; left: -240px;` to your img to have a much pretier start-position of your image (http://jsfiddle.net/6d4yC/14/)

Answer (score 3):

Simply add `overflow: hidden;` to your css for #box1. And as for your javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#box1").mouseenter(function(){
    $("img").stop().animate({width:'250px',height:'150px'},500);
  });
  $("#box1").mouseleave(function(){
    $("img").stop().animate({width:'600px',height:'200px'},500);
  });
});
```

Comment: @thenewseattle don't be so offensive, sometimes your busy typing an answer when someone else beats you to it